# Regex to extract number from string and convert them to float based on date logic

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
 7 months
 4 years 8 months
 1 year 7 months
 7 years 3 month
 6 months
<1 year
10+ years
```

I have a dataframe with one of the columns with data shown above. I want to convert this to the following out put

```
0.7
4.8
1.7
7.3
<.12
10.0+



df['years']=df['years'].replace(r'[years]','',regex=True)
df['years']=df['years'].replace(r'[months]','',regex=True)
```

I tried doing the above.
this logic does not work well. Is there a way to do this with regex?

Comment: Can you explain this: `<1 year` --> `<.12`?

Comment: Since number of months are unknown and <1 cannot be considered as 1.0 .  <.12 would say less than 12 months.

Comment: `^[ \t]*(?:(?:<(\d+)|(\d+)\+|(\d))[ \t]+years?)?[ \t]*(?:(?:<(\d+)|(\d+)\+|(\d))[ \t]+months?)?[ \t]*` and map it based on capture group being assigned.

Comment: this could be solved without dataframes, if the input would have been a text file

Comment: This is one of the columns of my dataFrame. Source of this data is not a text file . It comes from one of the table field from html file  that I scraped

Comment: @dvsn, using human being's algebra `<1 year` should be mapped to `<1.0` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [118]: to_repl = ['\s*([<>+\d]+)\s*year[s]?','\s*(\d+)\s*month[s]?']

In [119]: val = [r'\1',r'.\1']

In [120]: df['col'].replace(to_repl, val, regex=True).str.strip()
Out[120]:
0     .7
1    4.8
2    1.7
3    7.3
4     .6
5     <1
6    10+
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: :Could you explain the logic here . 4 years 8 months should be 4.8. This returns .48

Comment: @dvsn, glad it helps :)